# plotting svg via grImport2 works fine in terminal, not via knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-grid, grimport

The below chunk works fine inside the terminal, but ominously fails when run via knitr (or rather, rmarkdown).

````
---
title: "test-svg"
author: "foo"
date: "8/12/2018"
output: html_document
---

# Title

```{r}
# please download this file     https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcir2yuuyunw857/live_2_work.svg
# downloading in R may not work
# read it in / convert it
res <- grImport2::readPicture(file = "live_2_work.svg", warn = FALSE)
res <- grImport2::pictureGrob(picture = res)
# plot it on empty canvas
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(x = res)
# works!
```
````

Via knitr, it errors out with:

```
Error: 1: xmlParseEntityRef: no name 2: xmlParseEntityRef: no name (...)
```

I googled around but couldn't find anything about this, I am baffled why knitr behaves differently then normal plotting.

What's going on here?